# Proof of derivative of $x^n$ for all real n and real x

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, exponentiation

I've seen the following proof for the derivative of $x^n$:
$$
(x^n)' = (e^{ln(x)n})' = x^n \cdot \frac{n}{x} = nx^{n-1}
$$
But the equality $x^n = e^{ln(x)n}$ is only valid for $x \in (0,\infty)$.
How can one prove this property for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (Without using a complex logarithm)?

Comment: Check the case $x=0$ by hand, then notice $x = -(-x)$, and for $x<0$, we can apply the positive case to $-x$.

Comment: To me, this exercise doesn't make much sense. In your proof, you assumed more difficult claims to prove an easier one. Namely, chain rule and that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$. I guess this can be seen as a corollary to those proofs, but it's far easier ot prove the claim just using Binomial formula.

Comment: @zugzug But that's the entire point, the binomial formula is only valid for natural numbers, I want to prove this for all real numbers

Comment: what does $x^n$ even mean with $n$ real and $x$ negative?

Comment: @shanidahan Is $x^n$ with $x,n\in\mathbb{R}^+$ really any harder to define than $e^x$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$?

Answer (score 0):

The claim isn't exactly true since x^n is not defined for two real numbers. 
For example: (-1)^0.5 is complex

Comment: I'm aware, but what about $n = \frac{1}{3}$ for example? $x^(1/3)$ is defined for all real x

Comment: so you need to figure out where it will be true, because you won't be able to prove it for the general case.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be true if n is an irrational number. But for the rational case, if it is defined, you can use: $\left(-x\right)^{\dfrac{a}{b}}=\left(-1\cdot x\right)^{\dfrac{a}{b}}=\left(-1\right)^{\dfrac{a}{b}}\cdot x^{\dfrac{a}{b}}=\left(\sqrt[b]{-1}\right)^{a}\cdot x^{\dfrac{a}{b}}=\left(-1\right)^{a}\cdot x^{\dfrac{a}{b}}$